# SQL query via Python returns different results than direct SQL query. Why?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, flask, cs50

i am currently working on a website using html, flask, sqlite3 and Python.

in my python code i run this SQL query:

```
profile_rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM profile WHERE profile_id = :profile_id", profile_id=session["user_id"])
```

in the flask feed i can see that it works just fine and correctly inserts the id:

> SELECT * FROM profile WHERE profile_id = 11

The query does not return any rows like it should. it acts as if there was no row in the database.

if instead i run the code used by my program:

```
SELECT * FROM profile WHERE profile_id = 11
```

via "phpLiteAdmin v1.9.7.1" directly on the database i get the correct rows (those which are in the database and have the profile_id 11).

how can this happen? **I directly copied the query that was used by python (from the feed) into phpLiteAdmin** so it cannot give out a different result. **but it does!!!**. please help.

If it helps: i know that the query does not return a row because i tried the following things:

> 1

```
if len(profile_rows) == 0:
            return render_template("frontpage.html", warning="there are no rows in the db!")
```

returns the warning message

> 2

```
if profile_rows[0]["job"] is None:
            return redirect("/update_profile")
```

returns: "IndexError: list index out of range"

> 3

```
return render_template("frontpage.html", warning="row count: " + len(profile_rows))
```

returns the warning "row count: 0"

**with all other querys in my code this works just fine. just this one does not**

**reproductive example:**
Python:

```
import os
import sys

import hashlib, binascii, os
import time
from functools import wraps
from cs50 import SQL
from flask import Flask, flash, jsonify, redirect, render_template, request, session
from flask_session import Session
from tempfile import mkdtemp
from werkzeug.exceptions import default_exceptions, HTTPException, InternalServerError
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash

db = SQL("sqlite:///yourdatabase.db")

@app.route("/profile")
def profile():
        profile_rows = db.execute"SELECT * FROM profile WHERE profile_id = :profile_id", profile_id="1")


        if len(profile_rows) == 0:
            return render_template("profile.html", warning="row count: " + len(profile_rows))

        return render_template("profile.html")
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Profile</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% if warning != NULL %}
            <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                <strong>Warning!</strong> {{ warning }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    </body>
</html>
```

SQLite3:

```
CREATE TABLE 'profile' ('profile_id' integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 'title' varchar(150), 'text' varchar(15000), 'job' varchar(100), 'area' varchar(150))

INSERT INTO "profile" ("profile_id","title","text","job","area") VALUES ('1','Hello world,','test','job','workfield')
```

Comment: @snakecharmerb i am not inserting directly before if thats what you mean. I tried the code before and after reloading the site and the database. but it did not work at any of the times. What do you mean by "flushing the session" and how do i do it? i don't think i have ever heard of that.

Comment: Have you tried with a qmark style placeholder instead of :profile_id in your query?
https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects

Comment: @TerrySpotts yeah, sadly i've tried that too and it did not work

Comment: @snakecharmerb are you sure that flushing works with sqlite3? i've tried it but only gotten errors. Also i added a reproductive example. i hope that is enough.

Comment: I'd assumed you were using (flask-)sqlalachemy directly, but you're using cs50, which doesn't expose the session.  So no, flushing won't work.

Comment: @snakecharmerb okay, thanks for the try anyways. do you have any idea how i could work my way around this? because i cant finish my course if i don't get this right...

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it with the example code.  I'd suggest checking that your are definitely using the right  database file.

Comment: I know nothing of `cs50` but consider `sqlite3`, the built-in module of Python standard library and adheres to [PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/).

Comment: If you remove the `WHERE` clause entirely does it return results?

Comment: @TerrySpotts thanks for the help but the problem somehow solved itself. i did not even get to try that. As i restarted the program today it worked just fine without changing a thing on my code. maybe the programing enviroment was down or something.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the helpful comments. Somehow the problem solved itself. As i started the CS50 IDE today the program worked just fine without changing a single line of code. I don't know what the problem was but as long as it does not happen again thats fine by me. Have a great day everyone!!!

I cant close the topic today for some reason, so if somebody knows how this could happen i am all ears :D

I will close this in the next days